# my application not responding after Application_Start

Tags: asp.net, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3, freeze

I am having a serious problem, my application is not responding after Application_Start was executed, I have put breakpoints in Application_BeginRequest and a lot of other places, but it just keep there, loading forever.

I am really annoyed, I have not idea about how to solve this problem, no error, no timeout, just nothing.

Any ideas?

Is there any way to know the last line executed? I need a clue.

Comment: does the visual studio title bar say "(Running)" or "(Debugging)" at the end?

Comment: I press F5, it reaches all the breakpoints and execute well application_start after that it says (Running) and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running under IIS or the Visual Studio web server? You might want to restart IIS (for the former) or restart VS (for the latter)

Comment: I have test in both server, and in both I have the same results, nothing, just keeps loading.